# Java Client-Server

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

Почему сервер не принимает ввод от клиента?
В чем ошибка?

```
public class Client
{   
 public static void main(String[] args)
{

  try(Socket client=new Socket("192.168.56.1",7000);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())))
    {

        String Text;
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Text = sc.nextLine();
        pw.print(Text);
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        Text = sc.nextLine();
        pw.print(Text);


    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
 public class Server
{ 
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try(ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(7000))
    {
        System.out.println("Start");

        try (Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
             BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
             PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true))
        {
            pw.println("Write text");
            String terx = reader.readLine();
            pw.println("Text "+terx);
            String file;
            file=reader.readLine();

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Переведите свой вопрос, иначе вопрос закроют.

Comment: Я исправил.Так пойдет?

Comment: @СтепанАдамов нет, он всё ещё на английском языке.

Comment: Все,я исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `pw.println()` вместо `pw.print()`
Или
Добавляйте в конец строки `System.lineSeparator()`, после чего `pw.flush();`
Да, параметр `autoFlush = true` работает только с `println()`
[тыць](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479697/printwriter-or-any-other-output-stream-in-java-do-not-know-r-n)

Answer (score 0):

Это dead lock - сервер ждет, когда клиент что-то напишет, а клиент занят тем же - у сокета операция чтения блокирующая, пока не придет сообщение/сокет не закроется, так и будет висеть в ожидании.

Comment: Я изменил код.Почему сейчас не работает?Вроде тут нет такого что бы в один момент времени клиент и сервер ждали ввода

Comment: в клиенте замени `pw.print(Text);` на `pw.println(Text);`